# Why are Rails cookies disappearing in Functional Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cookies

In my Application Controller I am setting cookies in 3 places.  In a before filter...

```
def set_abingo_identity
  # skip bots
  if request.user_agent =~ /#{@robot_regular_expression}/i
    Abingo.identity = "robot"
  elsif current_user
    Abingo.identity = cookies[:abingo_identity] ||= 
          { :value => current_user.id, :expires => 1.year.from_now }
  else
    Abingo.identity = cookies[:abingo_identity] ||= 
          { :value => rand(10 ** 10), :expires => 1.year.from_now }
  end
end
```

... and in two methods...

```
def remember_visit url 
  20.times do |i| 
    # Add cookie to referrer list
    name = "referrer#{i}"
    if cookies[name].blank?
      cookies[name] = {:value => url, :expires => Time.now + 1.year }
      break
    elsif cookies[name] == url 
      break # skip
    end 
  end 
end
```

... and this one...

```
def set_referral_cookie val
  ref_name = "referral_id"
  offer_name = "offer_id"
  cur = cookies[ref_name]
  offer = cookies[offer_name]
  affiliate = Affiliate.find_by_name val
  if cur.blank? || offer.blank?
    if affiliate
      if cur.blank?
        cookies[ref_name] = { :value => affiliate.id.to_s, :expires => Time.now + 1.year }
      end
      if offer.blank? && affiliate.offer? && !affiliate.expired?
        cookies[offer_name] = { :value => affiliate.id.to_s, :expires => Time.now + 1.year }
      end
    end
  end
  return affiliate
end
```

Stepping through in the debugger, I see in the before filter, `cookies["abingo_identity"]` is set.  Then in remember_visit(), both it and `cookies["referrer0"]` are set, and then in set_referral_cookie(), all 3 are set.

But when I get back to my functional test, only `cookies["abingo_identity"]` is set.

The cookies["abingo_identity"] part is new, and when I comment it out, the other cookies persist.

What is wrong with this code?

Update:
They are not getting deleted, but they are not all copied to the test case's @response.cookies

Comment: Could this just be a result of [A/Bingo](https://github.com/ryanb/abingo) use when `current_user` is nil and you are generating a unique identity? Raise an issue in their project if it doesn't work as expected, because I don't see a test relating to cookies in master or any integration tests as of 2013-08-17, but it might be as simple as ensuring `current_user.id` the same id each time: https://github.com/ryanb/abingo/blob/master/test/abingo_test.rb

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be related to the TestCase's parsing of headers['Set-Cookie'], which has all 3 in it